# Django - Obtaining information from Requests POST Method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-requests

I am using the `requests` library with python 3.

My goal is a two-step process:

1. Send post request from python program to my Django app.
2. Process that post request by creating a new database entry with the information sent in said Django app.

I think the first part has been set-up properly, the development server registers the POST requests. However, I am having some trouble with step two.

I created a special url and html template just to see if anything gets picked up after I have made a POST request. The view is handled in this manner:

```
    def new_instance(request):
            instance = 'Nothing picked up!'

            if request.method == 'POST':
                    post = request.POST['ID']
                    instance = IDInstance(id=post)
                    instance.save()

            return render(
                    request,
                    'viewpage.html',
                     context = {'instance':instance})
```

However, neither the instance variable nor my database get updated.

The request that is being made looks like this:

```
Info = {'ID':'23234234'}
r = requests.post(domain,data=Info)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There's a discussion on CSRF protection on Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/

   The page also carries information on how to over-ride this. I had used "The Decorator Method" listed on the page, but I would recommend you read the page and decide what mechanism you want to use depending on your security requirements.
2. I had similar issue with local Node.js server too. Using [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/) helped fix it on my local system. You can give it a shot.

Comment: Instead of only linking to docs, it is better/more useful to copy over relevant portions of the document you have linked, to improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is effectively creating an API endpoint.

You should disable CSRF protection for this URL, as your external app will not have the token. This is fine to do.

For your second question, it's still not clear what you are confused about. Of course you will need a view; any action that is triggered by a request in Django is processed by a view. As I mentioned, there is no difference as far as Django is concerned between a request that is triggered by a user submitting a form in a browser, and an external process making a direct HTTP request. They work in exactly the same way.

Inside that view, you access the data via `request.POST` or `request.body`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply again, I've updated the question.